# How should I use PendingIntent to make a second call?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, system-calls, android-pendingintent

I would like to make two calls in a row in an android app. Upon clicking button the app calls the first number. I created the broadcastreceiver below, that detects when the first call ends. It should write out that "First call ended" and then call the second number. I think I should do it with PendingIntent. I wrote in my code with a comment where I think I have to write a method (which has parameters one of which is PendingIntent). Can anybody show me how can I get it done?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void calling(String phone) {


    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    callIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);
    startActivity(callIntent);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243 , callIntent, 0);

 //i think here should I use pendingIntent somehow, but I have no idea how





}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.CallButton);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calling("+11111111");








        }
    });


}



public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private CustomPhoneStateListener mPhoneListener;
    private String incoming_nr;
    private int prev_state;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;

        if (mPhoneListener == null) {
            mPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

            // TelephonyManager object
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


            // Register our listener with TelephonyManager
            telephony.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    /* Custom PhoneStateListener */
    class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(incomingNumber)) {
                incoming_nr = incomingNumber;
            }

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    prev_state = state;
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    prev_state = state;
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if ((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        // A call has now ended
                        //it writes out the call end, but does not call. why?
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        calling("+22222222");
                        prev_state = state;
                    }
                    else if ((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        // Rejected or Missed call
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Rejected Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        prev_state = state;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This code is without the pending intent

It will work in all cases if call is accepted, rejected or canceled.

Let me know if it work for you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button1,button2;
boolean FLAG = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.callButton2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == button1)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"number1"));
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+FLAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FLAG = true;
    }

    if(v == button2)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"number2"));
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(FLAG)
    {
        button2.performClick();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FLAG = false;
            }
        },5000);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+"resumed"+FLAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Comment: actually, the app should have only one button and upon clicking the button the app calls the first number. When the first call ends, it should automatically call the second number

Comment: Make a new method secondCall(); and instead of button2.performClick() call secondCall();